# Elasticsearch Query: Filter Documents Based on Nested Object Criteria, Ignoring Missing or Non-Matching Fields

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to filter Elasticsearch documents based on nested object criteria. Specifically, I want to retrieve documents where the field entity.interviewRounds.status either doesn't exist in any of the nested objects within the entity.interviewRounds array or, if it exists, its value must be "INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING."

example document JSON:

```
{
  "entity": {
   "interviewRounds": [
    {
     "sequenceNumberFromOne": 1,
     "status": "INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING"
    },
    {
     "sequenceNumberFromOne": 2
    }
   ],
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a modified Elasticsearch query to achieve this filtering behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've already tried the following query, but it returns documents if any one of the objects within the array doesn't contain the entity.interviewRounds.status field. I need help in crafting a query that will only return documents where all nested objects either don't contain the field or have it with a value of "INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING."

```
{
    "nested": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": [
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "entity.interviewRounds.status",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "entity.interviewRounds.sequenceNumberFromOne": {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "boost": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "entity.interviewRounds.status.keyword": {
                                            "value": "INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING",
                                            "boost": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
            }
        },
        "path": "entity.interviewRounds"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. You query returns all documents where nested field are either empty or pending. You just need to replace the top level `should` with `must_not` to make it return all fields where the nested object contains anything that returns anything but empty or pending.

In other words instead of

```
{
    "nested": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
```

try

```
{
    "nested": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                    {
```

Update: Here is a complete example

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "entity": {
        "properties": {
          "interviewRounds": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "sequenceNumberFromOne": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "status": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
                
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"entity":{"interviewRounds":[{"sequenceNumberFromOne":1,"status":"INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING"},{"sequenceNumberFromOne":2}]}}
{"index":{}}
{"entity":{"interviewRounds":[{"sequenceNumberFromOne":1,"status":"INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING"}]}}
{"index":{}}
{"entity":{"interviewRounds":[{"sequenceNumberFromOne":1,"status":"INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING"},{"sequenceNumberFromOne":2},{"sequenceNumberFromOne":3,"status":"INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_CONFIRMED"}]}}
{"index":{}}
{"entity":{"interviewRounds":[{"sequenceNumberFromOne":3,"status":"INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_CONFIRMED"}]}}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "entity.interviewRounds.status.keyword": {
                  "value": "INTERVIEW_SCHEDULE_PENDING",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "entity.interviewRounds.status",
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative": true,
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      "path": "entity.interviewRounds"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this change. It didn't work. no documents is getting matched. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: It is possible that your actual mapping is different from what I was able to deduce from your short description. I have posted a complete example with mapping, data and the request. I simplified request by removing sequence number check, but it works when you add it back.